# Transferring bearer token from API request to other tests using Cypress

Tags: jwt, authorization, cypress, bearer-token

I am running tests on a web application to test WYSIWYG functionality and XSS vulnerabilities. I use the following command before

```
beforeEACH(() => {
       cy.vaderAuth()
    });

Cypress.Commands.add('vaderAuth', () => {
  let config = Cypress.config();

  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: Cypress.config('tokenUrl') + '/api/v1?actions=api/v1/login',
    body: {
      username: config.horizon.username,
      password: config.horizon.password,
    }
  }).then(response => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('JWT', response.body['api/v1/login'].token)
  })
})
```

The above command successfully gets the Bearer Token but then the following test throws a 401 Unauthorised error.

```
it('Sending a regular API request to Welcome Messages', function() { 
        cy.request({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/api/v1/organisations/welcome-message?actions=api/v1/organisations/welcome-message/set-welcome-messages',
            body : {"welcome_messages":[{"message":"<p>Test investor welcome message!</p>","type":"User"},{"message":"<p>Internal User welcome message Cypress Test. </p>","type":"Internal User"},{"message":"<p>Test entrepreneur welcome message!</p>","type":"Entrepreneur"}]},
            headers : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + window.localStorage.JWT}
    })
})
```

[beforeEach working, API request 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rGh3.png)

[401 cypress error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnP9p.png)

I have checked the failure and it is sending the Bearer Token as a header, and the request headers match the headers the same request sends if I enter the Bearer Token manually as follows.

```
  it('Sending a regular API request to Welcome Messages', function() { 
        cy.request({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/api/v1/organisations/welcome-message?actions=api/v1/organisations/welcome-message/set-welcome-messages',
            body : {"welcome_messages":[{"message":"<p>Test investor welcome message!</p>","type":"User"},{"message":"<p>Internal User welcome message Cypress Test. </p>","type":"Internal User"},{"message":"<p>Test entrepreneur welcome message!</p>","type":"Entrepreneur"}]},
            //headers : {"Authorization": "Bearer (insertbearertokenhere)}
            
    })
})
```

When entering the Bearer Token manually the following tests all run smoothly with no error, but if I have to go in and change the Bearer Token every time I run these tests, it kind of defeats the point of automating it as by the time I've logged into my web app and got the token, I may as well test the application manually.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I have been working on it with no luck for around a week now.

Comment: I'm not really confident in the way you set auth header for your request, so it might happen that it is not read. Could you try to send `auth: {bearer: localStorage.getItem('JWT')}` and see the result? Also, I would recommend storing your token into `sessionStorage` instead, so the data will persist only until the window or tab is closed.

Comment: Generally I'd recommend not to make that request in beforeEach(), but in before(). To keep cookies over tests you can use [cy.preserveOnce()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html#Syntax).

Comment: @AlexIzbas Thanks for your reply, I have used your method and this has solved my problem, thank you so much for your help. I have also taken your advice on storing into `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`

Comment: @DarkMikey Thank you for your reply, I am fairly new to Cypress so thank you so much for your advice, I will change my tests accordingly.